# Access Google analytics v3 with apikey

Tags: c#, authentication, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have access GA using an ServiceAccount and OAuth2. Now I'm trying to do the same using a public APIKEY, but can not find a way to set credentials (username/password)

From what I can read inline this is possible using version 2.4 where you can set userCredentials on the AnalyticsService instance.

Now my question is if this is still supported in v3?

best regards

Comment: for plain username/password I ended up just using api versino 2.4. Aware that this will be deprecated later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the latest version 3 the plain username and password is not supported